# International Zip Code Search

Tags: geospatial

I implemented a U.S. "find near zip code" search for somebody.  The coordinates of U.S. zip codes come from a commercial zip code database.  Now, they would like a similar ability for countries other than the U.S.

Has anybody implemented something like this for non-U.S. searches?  How about general "find close to this address" searches?  What commercial data is available?

Comment: The client. "I implemented [search] for somebody ... now they would like ...". So "they" is clearly the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if GeoNames works for you:

http://www.geonames.org/

They've got a database of postal codes and another one of place names with coordinates.  You could combine the two to get what you want.

I can't say much more about this one, but they seem to offer a commercial database:

http://www.killetsoft.de/h_geod_e.htm

Answer (score 1):

UPU data is at http://www.upu.int/en/resources/postcodes/universal-postcoder-database.html